# Concatenate Scala Seqs in Java

Tags: java, scala

In my java code I have two scala `Seq<String>` objects that I want to concatenate into a single `Seq<String>`. I know something like the following is possible:

```java
Seq<String> seq1 = getSeq(1);
List<String> l1 = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seq1);
Seq<String> seq2 = getSeq(2);
List<String> l2 = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seq2);
l1.addAll(l2);
return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(l1.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
```

But converting from `Seq`s to `List`s back to `Seq`s is very inefficient. Is there a better way to do it while staying within java code?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the **Java** <-> **Scala** transformations aren't expensive, since those are just simple wrappers that doesn't copy the data.
The expensive part is `toSeq()` at the end, which I believe is unnecessary, do not transform an integrator, you can transform a **Java** `List` into a **Scala** `Seq`.

In any case, you also do not need to do all this, you can just call any of the methods provided by seq: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html

Thus, I am pretty sure you can just

```
seq1.concat(seq2)
```

Comment: Hmm. My IDE throws a "Cannot resolve method 'concat...'" warning when I try that. And how can I convert the lists without using `toSeq()`? The `JavaConverters` class doesn't have a method that takes `List`s directly, which is why I used `asScalaIteratorConverter`

Comment: @MikeS Yeah, your IDE can say whatever it wants, it doesn't matter. Does the compiler also show such error? Remember that IDEs do not use a real compiler, and they may lie for time to time, always check with the compiler; and if you get the same error, then provide more details on the question, **Scala** version, full imports, **Java** version, etc. - For your second question, I can see it right here: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/jdk/javaapi/CollectionConverters$.html#asScala[A](l:java.util.List[A]):scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[A]

Comment: @MikeS `concat` is from Scala 2.13. If you are using 2.12 or earlier you can use just `seq1.$plus$plus(seq2)` instead.